# HTML5 file api support in XTK

Tags: xtk

Is there a way or plan for reading files (images or color tables) from the local file system?

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is (since commit https://github.com/xtk/X/commit/f7f7e8c362dfcbb573394ff1668e0fe1e8e16f09)!

check out the following JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/haehn/TaeEF/

or the big version on the XTK Sandbox

http://sandbox.goxtk.com/fileapi_test/

You can choose up to

- 1 volume
- 1 labelmap
- 1 color table
- 1 mesh
- 1 curvature file
- 1 trk file

at once in the file dialog. Choosing files can be done multiple times - the limitation is only per file dialog.

Comment: The examples don't seem to work anymore. "Error: invalid arguments" was thrown in Firefox 15.